# How can Entity Framework queries be reused (using methods)?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to reuse part of a query, because it's complex enough that I want to try to avoid code duplication.

It seems that when calling any method inside a query, you end up with:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method {X} method, and
>   this method cannot be translated into
>   a store expression

What I would like to do ideally is use:

```
var q = from item in context.Items
        where item.SomeCondition == true
        select new {Item = item, Connections = GetConnections(item)};
```

`GetConnections` is the method that performs queries on `item`. I'm trying to reuse the (rather complex) query in `GetConnections`, but I'm not sure how to get this to work.

Current signature of GetConnections is something like:

```
IQuerable<Connection> GetConnections(MyItem item)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Expression<Func<Customer, CustomerWithRecentOrders>>
  GetCustomerWithRecentOrdersSelector()
{
  return c => new CustomerWithRecentOrders()
  {
    Customer = c,
    RecentOrders = c.Orders.Where(o => o.IsRecent)
  };
}
```

Then later...

```
var selector = GetCustomerWithRecentOrderSelector();
var q = myContext.Customers
  .Where(c => c.SomeCondition)
  .Select(selector);
```

Comment: Any idea how to do the same thing when you don't have an `IQuerable<Customer>` but just `Customer`? Is that even possible?

Comment: CustomerWithRecentOrders x = myContext.Customers .Where(c => c == myCustomer) .Select(selector).Single()

Answer (score -1):

Your query looks almost perfect to me. You can most certainly call `GetConnections(item)` from within you query; calling methods is legal. However, you have another issue: Anonymous type members must be created with member names (without those names, you would have no way to access them).

The following query compiles fine for me:

```
var q = from item in context.Items
        where item.SomeCondition == true
        select new {item = item, connections = GetConnections(item)};
```

Note the addition of `item =` and `connections =` to the `select`.

Please note, however, that your GetConnections() method may need to be `static` (mine was; I wasn't sure if you left that out accidentally or not).

Comment: It's not the compilation that fails, it's the execution. I didn't copy/paste the code in, but typed it by head instead, that's why I forgot the anonymous type members